# как получить содержимое файлов в папке?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

В папке есть файлы i18n.ru.json, i18n.en.json и т.д.. Они подключаются в файл. 
Сделал так:

```
function getMessages() {
  const locales = require.context('./', true, /i18n\.[a-z]+\.js$/i);
  const messages = {};

  locales.keys().forEach((key) => {
    const parts = key.split('.');
    const lang = parts[2];
    messages[lang] = require(`./i18n.${lang}.js`).default;
  });

  return {
   messages,
  };
}

export default getMessages();
```

Не устраивает то, что require берет список файлов в папке с модулем, поэтому приходится копировать этот файл в папку с каждым компонентом, где нужна интернационализация.

Попробовал сделать через fs.readdirSync, но cli задизейблил использование модуля fs в конфиге webpack.

Вопрос: как сделать так, что бы файл не копировать в каждую папку с компонентом, а что бы получать содержимое как-то так:

```
import getI18n from 'path/to/module'
const i18n = getI18n();
```